# Stackoverflow error when using stringbuilder and recursion

Tags: memory, recursion, stack, stringbuilder

How can I clean the stack memory as the recursion goes on? I wouldn't need the first strings stored, only say the last half. So is it possible to clean out the strings that are unused in order to make more stack memory available? I have tried garbage collector, no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow happens because your recursion is too deep you can't clean this part of the memory you need to think how to avoid such a deep recursion or skip it altogether.